# Spark : Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. Struct<name,id> != Struct<id,name>

Tags: apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql, union

Error :
    Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. 
    **struct(tier:string,skyward_number:string,skyward_points:string) <> struct(skyward_number:string,tier:string,skyward_points:string)** at the first column of the second table;;

Here order of the struct fields is different but rest everything is same.

dataframe1 Schema

```
root
 |-- emcg_uuid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phone_no: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- travel_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gdpr_restricted_flg: string (nullable = false)
 |-- gdpr_reason_code: string (nullable = false)
 |-- document: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- skyward: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- tier: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_number: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_points: string (nullable = false)

dataframe2 schema
root
 |-- emcg_uuid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phone_no: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- travel_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gdpr_restricted_flg: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gdpr_reason_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- document: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- skyward: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_number: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- tier: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_points: string (nullable = false)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//preserves the order the columns while doing union
  def getStructRecursiveDataFrame(df1 : DataFrame, df2 : DataFrame,columns : Array[String]) : DataFrame = {
    if(columns.isEmpty) {
      df2
    }
    else {
      println("test")
      val col_name = columns.head
      val col_schema = df1.schema.fields.find(_.name == col_name).get
      if(col_schema.dataType.typeName.equals("struct")){
        println("test1")
        val updatedStructNames: Seq[Column] = col_schema.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fieldNames.map(name => col(col_name+"." + name))
        getStructRecursiveDataFrame(df1,df2.withColumn(col_name, struct(updatedStructNames: _*)),columns.tail)
      }
      else{ getStructRecursiveDataFrame(df1,df2,columns.tail)}
    }
  }

  def unionByName(a:  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, b:  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame):  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {

    val b_new_df = getStructRecursiveDataFrame(a,b,a.columns)
    val columns_seq = a.columns.toSet.intersect(b_new_df.columns.toSet).map(col).toSeq
    a.select(columns_seq: _*).union(b_new_df.select(columns_seq: _*))
  }
```

Results

```
[INFO] DATAFRAME-1 SCHEME
root
 |-- emcg_uuid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phone_no: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- travel_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gdpr_restricted_flg: string (nullable = false)
 |-- gdpr_reason_code: string (nullable = false)
 |-- document: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- skyward: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- tier: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_number: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_points: string (nullable = false)

[INFO] DATAFRAME-2 SCHEME
root
 |-- emcg_uuid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phone_no: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- travel_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gdpr_restricted_flg: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gdpr_reason_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- document: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- skyward: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_number: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- tier: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_points: string (nullable = false)

[INFO] DATAFRAME SCHEME AFTER THE UNION
root
 |-- skyward: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_number: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- tier: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- skyward_points: string (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- document: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- phone_no: string (nullable = true)
 |-- travel_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gdpr_restricted_flg: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gdpr_reason_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- emcg_uuid: string (nullable = true)

[INFO] TEST CASE FOR ANONYMIZATION VALIDATION
[INFO] INPUT DATA
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|name|phone_no  |travel_type|gdpr_restricted_flg|dob       |gdpr_reason_code|country|emcg_uuid|document                                   |skyward          |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|ravi|8747436090|freq       |                   |1988-05-28|                |dubai  |uuid_1   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> A3343)|[123456,blue,687]|
|aaaa|8747436091|freg       |                   |1988-06-25|                |europe |uuid_2   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> A3341)|[123456,blue,687]|
|bbbb|8747436092|reg        |                   |1988-07-26|                |india  |uuid_3   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> A3345)|[123456,blue,687]|
|cccc|8747436093|na         |                   |1988-08-27|                |georgia|uuid_4   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> A3349)|[123456,blue,687]|
|dddd|8747436094|na         |                   |1988-09-29|                |swis   |uuid_5   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> B3343)|[123456,blue,687]|
|null|8747436095|freq       |                   |1988-02-30|                |us     |uuid_6   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> C3343)|[123456,blue,687]|
|null|8747436096|na         |                   |1988-01-01|                |canada |uuid_7   |Map(document_type -> null, id -> D3343)    |[123456,blue,687]|
+----+----------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+

[INFO] EXPECTED OUTPUT
+-------+----------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|name   |phone_no  |travel_type|gdpr_restricted_flg|dob       |gdpr_reason_code|country|emcg_uuid|document                                   |skyward          |
+-------+----------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|DDDDDDD|9999999   |freq       |Y                  |1988-05-XX|13-001          |XXXXXXX|uuid_1   |Map(document_type -> ZZZZZ, id -> HH343)   |[123456,blue,687]|
|aaaa   |8747436091|freg       |                   |1988-06-25|                |europe |uuid_2   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> A3341)|[123456,blue,687]|
|DDDDDDD|9999999   |reg        |Y                  |1988-07-XX|13-001          |XXXXXXX|uuid_3   |Map(document_type -> ZZZZZ, id -> HH345)   |[123456,blue,687]|
|cccc   |8747436093|na         |                   |1988-08-27|                |georgia|uuid_4   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> A3349)|[123456,blue,687]|
|dddd   |8747436094|na         |                   |1988-09-29|                |swis   |uuid_5   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> B3343)|[123456,blue,687]|
|null   |8747436095|freq       |                   |1988-02-30|                |us     |uuid_6   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> C3343)|[123456,blue,687]|
|null   |9999999   |na         |Y                  |1988-01-XX|13-001          |XXXXXXX|uuid_7   |Map(document_type -> null, id -> HH343)    |[123456,blue,687]|
+-------+----------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+

[INFO] ACTUAL OUTPUT
+-------+----------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|name   |phone_no  |travel_type|gdpr_restricted_flg|dob       |gdpr_reason_code|country|emcg_uuid|document                                   |skyward          |
+-------+----------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|DDDDDDD|9999999   |freq       |Y                  |1988-05-XX|13-001          |XXXXXXX|uuid_1   |Map(document_type -> ZZZZZ, id -> HH343)   |[UUUUU,blue,JJ7] |
|aaaa   |8747436091|freg       |                   |1988-06-25|                |europe |uuid_2   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> A3341)|[123456,blue,687]|
|DDDDDDD|9999999   |reg        |Y                  |1988-07-XX|13-001          |XXXXXXX|uuid_3   |Map(document_type -> ZZZZZ, id -> HH345)   |[UUUUU,blue,JJ7] |
|cccc   |8747436093|na         |                   |1988-08-27|                |georgia|uuid_4   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> A3349)|[123456,blue,687]|
|dddd   |8747436094|na         |                   |1988-09-29|                |swis   |uuid_5   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> B3343)|[123456,blue,687]|
|null   |8747436095|freq       |                   |1988-02-30|                |us     |uuid_6   |Map(document_type -> passport, id -> C3343)|[123456,blue,687]|
|null   |9999999   |na         |Y                  |1988-01-XX|13-001          |XXXXXXX|uuid_7   |Map(document_type -> null, id -> HH343)    |[UUUUU,blue,JJ7] |
+-------+----------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------------+-------+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Can anyone convert this solution to python?

Answer (score 7):

The default Spark behaviour for `union` is standard SQL behaviour, so match-by-position. This means, the schema in both DataFrames must contain the same fields with the same fields in the same order.

If you want to match schema by name, use `unionByName`, introduced in Spark 2.3.

You can also re-map fields:

```
val df1 = ...
val df2 = /...
df1.toDF(df2.columns: _*).union(df2)
```

Edit: I saw the edit now.

You can add again those columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val withCorrectedStruct = df1.withColumn("skyward", struct($"skyward_number", $"tier", $"skyward_points"))
```

Comment: if we see the schema for the two dataframes, except for fields inside the struct remaining everything is in proper order.

Comment: thx,but the problem is I'm creating struct columns dynamically, in this case it is one column skywards, but for some dataframes / tables it is arbitrary no.of  struct columns, so I need a function which can work even when the order inside the struct column differs

Comment: @ravi, got it. I'll think how to deal with this automatically

Comment: @Gaweda, yes we need to deal this automatically as I'm writing a generic solution to mask the personal information in the tables

Answer (score 0):

If only one field different, and name is known ("skyward"), can be resolved as:

```
val data = List(("1", "2", "3"))
val bulkDF = data.toDF("emcg_uuid", "tier", "skyward_number")

// union parts
val tsDF = bulkDF.withColumn("skyward", struct($"tier", $"skyward_number"))
val stDF = bulkDF.withColumn("skyward", struct($"skyward_number", $"tier"))

// change struct "skyward" in last stDF
val schema = tsDF.schema.fields.find(_.name == "skyward").get
val updatedStructNames: Seq[Column] = schema.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fieldNames.map(name => col("skyward." + name))
val withUpdatedSchema = stDF.withColumn("skyward", struct(updatedStructNames: _*))

// union
tsDF.union(withUpdatedSchema).show(false)
```

For many such struct fields just some loops can be used.

Comment: Thx! I just modified union function to work for struct column with different order of fields

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue "Error : Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types.".

Investigated below possibilities which could be causing the issue.

1. schema mismatch between dataset1 and dataset2 - My case it was matching.
2. Column ordering between dataset1 and dataset2 - there is a mismatch in the column ordering caused an issue.
   to maintain column order in dataset1 and dataset2 followed below steps,

   print the schema of both dataset1 and dataset2 to know the current column order
   align column of dataset1 based on dataset2 or vice versa.
   ****Example**:
   datset1(column2, column1) dataset2(column1, column1)
   datset1.select("column1","column2")).union(dataset2)** - will arrange the column and problem solved.